# Missing options in settings page in Voyager Laravel admin panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I just installed Voyager in my Laravel Project. Now in my admin panel in Voyager in settings page I am unable to get options like changing Logo, Title etc. from my admin panel.
Here is the snips of my admin panel.
[I am missing options for changing basic stuffs in my panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwj8O.png)

I am getting this in my title bar.
[My page title is null I am getting only ' - '.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvzFE.png)
Laravel Version: 5.4
Voyager: 0.11.14
php: 7.x
mysql: 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because, you haven't created any setting variables in the setting menu of voyager, so all you have to do is to create certain settings in the admin panel like admin_title (field type text), admin_description (field type text area),

[image: as shown in this picture] once you have created these setting voyager will pick them for its admin title and admin description.

if you want any such other setting(s) create our own custom field and you can use them anywhere in your project like :

```
Voyager::setting('your_custom_field_settings')
```

you can also use some nice cheatsheet for voyager at [here](https://voyager-cheatsheet.ulties.com/). i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You I got the issue actually I thought that when we run command  `php artisan voyager:install`  is automatically creates the table settings and feeds the default values but In my case it didn't happen so. Anyways It worked thank you!